# Adjust width of algorithm float

Tags: floats, algorithms, width

I am writing a code using the `algorithm` package. However, I would like to put smaller edges. I used the `minipage`, boxes and did not work. Could someone give me a suggestion?

I have this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
%========================
\begin{document}  
 \section*{Example Algorithm} 
 %---------------------- 
   \begin{algorithm}
   \caption{Penalty function}   
     \begin{itemize}
        \item Let $\{c_k\}$, $k=1,2,\ldots$, be a sequence tending to infinity such that for each $k$, $0 \leq c_k < c_{k+1}$.  
        \item Define the function $$q(\mu_{k},x) = f(x) + \mu_{k}P(x).$$
        \item For each k solve the problem        
              \begin{gather*}  minimize \ q(\mu_{k},x), \end{gather*}
             obtaining a solution point $x_{k}$.
     \end{itemize}
   \end{algorithm} 
 %----------------------
\end{document}
```

which results

[image]

but, I want

[image]

Comment: A solution for putting a floating environment into minipage is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215090/putting-algorithm-in-minipage) and it works for this problem. You just have to add `[H]` behind `\begin{algorithm}` and it works in the `minipage`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `algorithm` float is defined using [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)'s `\newfloat`. As a result, the entire float is consumed for possible restructuring (including the placement of the `\caption`, which depends on the style). This also affects the possibility of adjusting the width of the float.

One way around this would be to place the float inside a `minipage` and make it not float. This is supported by the `float` package's `[H]` float specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm}

\begin{document}  

\section*{Example Algorithm} 

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Penalty function}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Let $\{c_k\}$, $k = 1,2,\dots$, be a sequence tending to infinity such that for each~$k$, $0 \leq c_k < c_{k+1}$.  
    \item Define the function $$q(\mu_{k},x) = f(x) + \mu_k P(x).$$
    \item For each k solve the problem        
          \[ \text{minimize } q(\mu_k,x),c \]
          obtaining a solution point~$x_k$.
  \end{itemize}
\end{algorithm}

{\centering
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Penalty function}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Let $\{c_k\}$, $k = 1,2,\dots$, be a sequence tending to infinity such that for each~$k$, $0 \leq c_k < c_{k+1}$.  
      \item Define the function $$q(\mu_{k},x) = f(x) + \mu_k P(x).$$
      \item For each k solve the problem        
            \[ \text{minimize } q(\mu_k,x),c \]
            obtaining a solution point~$x_k$.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\par
}

\end{document}
```

Of course, using a `minipage` *requires* one to use `\begin{algorithm}[H]` (to avoid the floating behaviour). If you still want a floating `algorithm`, you can use the following work-around:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      % <your algorithm>
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

We place the non-float `algorithm` inside a floating `figure` *without* using a `\caption` for the `figure`.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. I preferred to use the figure environment because this style is the best for my text.

Comment: The second solution gives me an error: `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Comment: A working (although not so pretty) floating solution is this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132425/77953

Comment: @6005 just in case anyone's facing the same error, you're probably not suppressing your `algorithm`'s floating with `[H]`. The second solution *does* work as long as you don't have floats inside the `minipage`.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm}

\begin{document}  

\begin{algorithm}
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{%caption
        }
        \label{%label
        }
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                % Your algorithm here
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{minipage}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? [This code](https://pastebin.com/raw/4mi1A0mJ) produces an algorithm that is still taking up the full width of the line for the `\caption`; only the `algorithmic` part is spread out ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQGFQ.png)). Also, you need `algorithmic` or some other package to use the `algorithmic` environment.