# reduce border line on algorithm in LaTex

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to include a centered algorithm in a single column latex document on overleaf, however as can be seen from the picture, the border requires to be shortend in width to look and fit the page better.

How can I reduce the width of the top and bottom lines, so that they only cover the text, but remain centered on the page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{apacite}



\begin{document}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\large{\textit{header
}}}
\rfoot{Copyright $\textcopyright$ 2018+}
\cfoot{}
\sffamily
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\begin{center}
\huge{\textbf{Title}}
\end{center}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\begin{flushleft}
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\large{\textbf{authors}}
\vspace{5mm}
\par
\large{\textit{School}}
\par
\large{\textit{No emails (please)}}
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{ABSTRACT}}}
\sfdefault
\par
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
abstract. 
\vspace{5mm}
\par 
\textit{Keyword:} 
\par  
\vspace{5mm}
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\vspace{5mm}
\par



\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{1 \quad \quad INTRODUCTION}}}
\sfdefault
\par
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
Describe the general perspective of the chapter. Toward the end, specifically state the objectives of the chapter. 
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{BACKGROUND (SUBHEAD STYLE 1- ARIAL, SIZE 12, BOLD)}}}
\sfdefault
\par
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
Provide broad definitions and discussions of the topic and incorporate views of others (literature review) into the discussion to support, refute or demonstrate your position on the topic.
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{MAIN FOCUS OF THE CHAPTER}}}
\sfdefault
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\cite{TEIXEIRA2017}




\begin{algorithm}
    \centering
    \caption{title}\label{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State \text{algorithm} 
        \Repeat
        \State \text{/*Parse data to format*/}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{algorithm}$ 
        \State $\text{Pad data arrays with 0s}$ 
        \EndFor
        \Until {Data is converted}
        \State \text{algorithm}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{algorithm}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{algorithm}$ 
        \EndFor
        \Until {algorithm}
        \State \textbf{Return}  \text{algorithm}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{2 \quad \quad INTRODUCTION2}}}
\sfdefault

\end{flushleft}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{2 \quad \quad REFERENCE}}}
\sfdefault
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sa.bib}



\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Related (although with a different algorithm package): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215090/putting-algorithm-in-minipage. The idea is that if you put the algorithm in a `minipage` environment smaller than the full width, then the lines will be smaller as well.

Comment: @Marijn thanks for suggestion. I tried that but didnt seem to work thanks

Comment: @Bat if you tried it you could put it into the question, saying _I tried the following code but it resulted in the following error/the following wrong output:_ Also, it is good that you provided an MWE, but this code is not really minimal (the M from MWE). For example, the bibliography does not have anything to do with your question, so it should not be in the MWE. The idea is that it is as small as possible, while still a complete document/compilable/working (the W) and still showing your problem (the E).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to put the `algorithm` environment in a `minipage` environment, as in [Putting algorithm in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215090/putting-algorithm-in-minipage). The minipage allows to specify the width, for example `0.5\textwidth`.

Note that `algorithm` is a floating environment, therefore it cannot be used in a minipage directly, but only when floating is disabled with the `[H]` argument (i.e., [H]ere).

To center the algorithm on the page you can put it in a `center` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textit{header}}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{title}\label{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State \text{algorithm} 
        \Repeat
        \State \text{/*Parse data to format*/}
        \Until {Data is converted}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that worked perfectly. I must not have folowed the instructions on the webpage you provided correctly. Many thanks for your help. I have another formatting query I am struggling with, but does not pertain to algorithms - should I start a new questions rather than post here ?

Comment: @Bat you're welcome. If you have another unrelated problem then asking a new question is better - however, maybe the new question is already answered somewhere on the site, so make sure to check that first.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to limit the width of the algorithm, your easiest option is to place it in a `minipage` using a pre-specified width and place it inside a `center` environment (using the `[H]` float specifier for the `algorithm` environment. You can still make it float by placing the entire construction inside a `figure`, if you wish

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{<width>}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      <your algorithm>
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The `\caption` within the `algorithm` would work as expected, using only the `figure` environment as a floating mechanism.

If you want to find the true (natural) width of the algorithm, you can use [`varwidth`](//ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)'s similarly-named environment `varwidth` to capture the width of the `algorithmic` environment contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\algbox}
\algrenewcommand{\Return}{\State \textbf{return}~}

\begin{document}

% Capture the algorithm pseudo-code inside a box; maximum width will be \linewidth
\begin{lrbox}{\algbox}
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \State algorithm
      \Repeat
        \State /*Parse data to format*/
        \For{$i \gets 1, rows$}
          \State algorithm
          \State Pad data arrays with 0s
        \EndFor
      \Until Data is converted
      \State algorithm
      \Repeat
        \State algorithm
        \For{$i \gets 1, rows$}
          \State algorithm
        \EndFor
      \Until algorithm
      \Return algorithm
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}% Or use a figure environment and \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\algbox}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Algorithm title}
      \usebox{\algbox}% Use algorithm pseudo-code box
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks I went with the minipage suggestion and it worked perfectly ! many thanks for your help !